# throw new TypeError('app.use() requires middleware functions');

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport-local, passport.js

I am following an online course on Nodejs and was trying to implement basic authentication in my express application. But I am getting error on **app.use(new localStrategy(User.Authenticate());** I have tried reinstalling the 'passport-local'. Why this error keeps persisting ?

```
var express = require('express'), 
app = express(), 
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
passport = require('passport'),
User = require('./models/user'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
localStrategy = require('passport-local');   ;
passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/auth_DB');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static('images'));

app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: 'pppppqpqsda dasdqw ksndfkjnzmmuawt8ikweabmdsfj a',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false 
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // body...
    res.render('home');
});

app.get('/secret', function (req, res) {
    // body...
    res.render('secret');
});



app.get('/register', function (req, res) {
    // body...
    res.render('signup');
});

app.post('/register', function (req, res) {

    User.register(new User({username: req.body.username}), req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.render('signup');
        }

    passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function(){
        res.redirect('/secret');
    });

});

});


app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    // body...
    res.render('signin');
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', 
              {successRedirect: '/secret', 
               failureRedirect: '/login'} ),
    function(req, res){});


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server Started!');
});
```

Package.json :-

```
{
  "name": "test-auth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Testing the authentication",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Rishabh & Colt",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "ejs": "^2.5.6",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.7",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

User.js:-

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Error:-

```
C:\Users\Atom\Project\testAuth\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210
    throw new TypeError('app.use() requires middleware functions');
    ^

TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions
    at EventEmitter.use (C:\Users\Atom\Project\testAuth\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Atom\Project\testAuth\app.js:37:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:508:3
```

Comment: You posted a lot of code, but forgot about the most important detail: error message.

Comment: Can we also see `User = require('./models/user')` The problem is most likely here.

Comment: @dfsq Sorry, i'll add it, new to stackoverflow...

Comment: @magreenberg at the bottom of the post i have added user.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code has some typo. `localStrategy` is not a middleware for express. It can be used with `passport`.

Replace

```
app.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
```

with

```
passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I know it's a stupid mistake. I have been struggling with this for an hr now.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to require the wrong module
You are requiring local strategy this way

`LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');`

but in docs, you need to add '.Strategy'

http://passportjs.org/docs/configure

```
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
```

Comment: @yongsung.yoon 's solution seems to be working.  Yes, I saw it on some places online. Thanks ^^